# Collaborative WPF Application - Multiple Keyboards and Mice

Tags: wpf

I need to design a collaborative WPF application that allows multiple users to **simultaneously** edit **different** portions of the UI.

This *has* to be done using a single application, running on a single computer, displaying on a single projector - but with many keyboards and mice. Having a computer per user in a collaborative/meeting room environment is out of the question.

I have a general idea of how to do this - using raw input, simulating mouse pointers within the application, and somehow partitioning the application (in terms of events and focus) so that each partition accepts its own set of input events, and each maintains its own keyboard and mouse focus.

Has anyone done this before or knows of a better way to approach this challenge? Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will get this behavior from WPF. And if it is even possible it's going to be a hell lot of work.

Not to mention that, even though WPF supports the concept of N logical focus scopes, you can only have the Keyboard focus in one element at a time.

I would just make a regular WPF application, and search for a solution using some software such as [this](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/free-software-downloads/control-one-computer-with-multiple-keyboards-and-mice/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! WPF clearly was not intended for this sort of thing, but I'm going to try anyway. I will allocate some time this weekend for experimenting, and report back with my results some time next week.